# invoke manually button click event in c++ builder

Tags: events, button, invoke, c++builder-6

Using c++ builder borland (bcb6).

I wish to invoke manually button click event. I did:

```
FMap->bbDoneInClick(NULL);
```

While `Done` button located on the `FMap` form, but something went wrong with that.

Do I need to call `bbDoneInClick` with different parameters and not with `NULL` ?

Comment: I would change the `invoke` with `force` ... invoke means something else

Comment: "*something went wrong with that*" - you need to be more specific than that.  WHAT went wrong exactly? Was there an error? An exception? Unexpected behavior?  What does `bbDoneInClick()` actually do? In any case, `TButton` has a public `Click()` method that triggers the `OnClick` event handler if one is assigned.  You should be calling that instead of the `OnClick` handler directly: `FMap->bbDoneIn->Click();` (assuming the button is named `bbDoneIn`, otherwise replace with the correct name).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `NULL` use the `Form1` or the `bbDone` itself ...

- it depends on the event code itself how it uses the `Sender` parameter
- Also you can call the event handler safely only if the form is already created
- if it does not access Canvas you can use it even in `TForm1::TForm1` constructor
- if it does you need to take care of not using it prior to `OnShow` or `OnActivate`
- to avoid VCL problems or App crashes
- for common handlers it is sufficient to use main window ... (I use `this` instead of `NULL`)
- if you have single even handler for multiple components then the even is usually deciding the operation or target from the `Sender` parameter so in that case you need to pass the pointer to component itself